# ¿Es posible agrupar options en optiongroups según sus valores traídos de la BBDD?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo las tablas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Siguiendo la lógica de la cardinalidad, estoy intentando agrupar cada especialidad médica (option) en una profesión (optgroup). ¿La magia está en el query de la BBDD o un proceso en el front?

De momento la consulta que tengo es:

```
SELECT
em.id_especialidad, pm.nombre_profesion, em.nombre_especialidad, em.descripcion
FROM especialidades_medicas em
INNER JOIN profesiones_medicas pm
ON em.profesion_medica_id = pm.id_profesion_medica
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola un gusto saludarte.

si no entendi mal quieres que el optiongroup te muestre la categoria padre y abajo las hijas ordenadas.

Si es asi uso esta función, que quizas no sea la mejor pero me ha funcionado:

```html
function __etiqueta_select($cargos , $name, $id = null ){

    foreach($cargos as $row){
        $group[] = array(
            "option" => $row['cargo'],
            "group" => $row['departamento'],
            "value" => $row['id_cargo']
        );
    }

    $priorGroup = "";
    $html = "<select name='{$name}' id='cargo' class='bs-select form-control select2'>";
    $html .= "<option value='null'> -- Seleccione -- </option>"; //show option(s)
    foreach ($group AS $entry){
        if ($entry["group"] != $priorGroup){ //Start new optgroup if group changed.
            if ($priorGroup != ""){ //close prior optgroup if prior group WAS set.
                $html .= "</optgroup>";
            }
            $html .= "<optgroup label='{$entry["group"]}'>";
        }
        if($id != null){
            if($id == $entry["value"]){
                $html .= "<option value='{$entry["value"]}' selected>{$entry["option"]}</option>";
            } else {
                $html .= "<option value='{$entry["value"]}'>{$entry["option"]}</option>";
            }
        } else {
            $html .= "<option value='{$entry["value"]}'>{$entry["option"]}</option>";
        }
        $priorGroup = $entry["group"]; //update priorGroup.
    }
    $html .= "</optgroup></select>"; //close last optgroup + select.
    echo $html;
}
```

Y la uso asi:

```html
__etiqueta_select($array_cargos , 'cargo');
```

Me Arroja este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haberte ayudado o darte una idea de lo que necesitas.